# Why does this LINQ query new up only one instance of the internal List?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, linq-to-sql

Upon request, I have simplified this question.  When trying to take two generic List and blend them, I get unexpected results.

```
private List<ConditionGroup> GetConditionGroupParents()
{    
    return (from Conditions in dataContext.Conditions
               orderby Conditions.Name
               select new ConditionGroup
               {
                   GroupID = Conditions.ID,
                   GroupName = Conditions.Name,
/* PROBLEM */      MemberConditions = new List<Condition>()
               }).ToList();
}

private List<ConditionGroup> BuildConditionGroups()
{
    var results = GetConditionGroupParents();

    // contents of ConditionMaps is irrelevant to this matter
    List<ConditionMap> ConditionMaps = GenerateGroupMappings();

    // now pair entries from the map into their appropriate group,
    // adding them to the proper List<MemberConditions> as appropriate

    foreach (var map in ConditionMaps)
    {
        results.Find(groupId => groupId.GroupID == map.GroupID)
               .MemberConditions.Add(new ConditionOrphan(map));
    }

    return results;
}
```

I would expect each map in ConditionMaps to be mapped to a single ConditionGroup's MemberConditions in the "results.Find...." statement.

Instead, each map is being added to the list of *every* group, and that happens simultaneously/concurrently.

```
[edit] I've since proven that there is only a single instance of 
       List<Memberconditions>, being referenced by each group.

       I unrolled the creation of the groups like so:

       .
       .
       .    
       /* PROBLEM */      MemberConditions = null }).ToList();

      foreach (var result in results)
      {
          List<Condition> memberConditions = new List<Condition>();
          results.MemberConditions = memberConditions;
      }

      return results;

      In that case I was able to watch each instantiation stepping 
      through the loop, and then it worked as expected.  My question 
      remains, though, why the original code only created a single 
      instance.  Thanks!
      .
```

Why doesn't the LINQ query in GetConditionGroupParents "new up" a unique MemberConditions list for each Group, as indicated in the /* PROBLEM */ comment above?

Any insight is appreciated.  Thanks!

Jeff Woods of 
Reading, PA

Comment: please make questions short and add only the offending code. add more code only on demand

Comment: You should move to Entity framework, because Linq-to-SQL was never known for it's capability in interpreting queries.

Comment: @Euphoric the opposite is true. The 5 year old deprecated L2S still interprets more LINQ patterns than EF does. This is preventing me from migrating some things.

Comment: @Jeff prove that it is the same instance by using object.ReferenceEquals or using the VS debugger feature "Object IDs". Then, create a minimal repro (here about 10 lines) and report the bug.

Comment: Euphoric, moving to EF isn't possible.  The DBML behind this is 415 tables as part of a 140 project, 2 solution enterprise suite, and there are associated factories and repositories written against them all.

Comment: @usr, I was able to confirm it was only a single instance, by unrolling the creation of the groups.  See addition to the question above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. As a workaround you can create a factory function

```
static List<T> CreateList<T>(int dummy) { ... }
```

And pass it any dummy value depending on the current row such as `Conditions.ID`.

This trick works because L2S, unlike EF, is capable of calling non-translatable functions in the last `Select` of the query. You will not have fun migrating to EF since they have not implemented this (yet).

Comment: Thanks!  At least I'm not slowly going mad!  Do you happen to have a cite to a technote or other official documentation on this being a bug?

Comment: I don't. This is my diagnosis. It will never be fixed since L2S is abandoned. I wish they were releasing the source and allowing a fork to live on.